# how to groupby items and also put rows into column with categorical data

Tags: python, pandas

```
proj_name  department  responsible_name
aaaaaaaaa  a           xxxxx xxxxx
aaaaaaaaa  b           xxxxx xxxxy
aaaaaaaaa  c           xxxxx xxxxz
```

I want to put them into

```
proj_name  a             b             c
aaaaaaaaa  xxxxx xxxxx   xxxxx xxxxy   xxxxx xxxxz
```

I did try pivot table but it shows that index having duplicate, even melt still not get what I want

Comment: ```ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape```
I have tried it

Comment: @Khemakorn - then check duplicate for `pivot_table` solutions.